# Make a copy to clipboard function via JavaScript(jQuery) and Python(Flask)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to look this up a few days now but came out empty handed
I have a little website I'm working on and I've created a context menu (right click on a table row to get the context menu) and I wish to create a copy to clipboard method,
I've a the data I wish to copy on a variable named $text
This is the JS code:

```js
copy: {
    name: "Copy",
    callback: function (key, option) {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var $text = $row.find(".md").text();
    
    //the $text is what I'm trying to copy
    }
```

I've tried many method to do so, using JS only and when I didn't find any method to do so I've tried to find a way to send this variable to my **init**.py code which runs the server but without success.

I would very apprachet if anyone will be able to help me understand what am I looking for to make this work and how to implement it.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm afraid that the Flask Backend has nothing to do with copying data to the user clipboard.

Comment: You can find more information about copy with Javascript in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: I saw this post but here they give this idea to make a pop-up with a place from which you can copy, I hope that after clicking the Copy tab it would just save the part of the table I want to the clipboard (which I already got into $text)

Comment: OHHHH GOD I've got it, I didn't see the next part where he explained the way to it without the pop-up, You are awesome!